# PlantUML: overlapping activations (multiple threads)

Tags: uml, plantuml

I am trying to show overlapping activations in my sequence diagram (I am using PlantUML) but they are showing as nested activations:

For example:

```
@startuml
participant T1
participant T2
participant Main

T1 -> Main ++ #red: start
T2 -> Main ++ #yellow: start

Main --> T1 -- #red : done
Main --> T2 -- #yellow : done

@enduml
```

This will show nested red/yellow activations while I was expecting red to finish before yellow.

Is this supported? Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If I understand the question properly, you are trying to show that `Main` can be actived in parallel. If so, you should use a **par** fragment to indicate parallel operations (see [Parallel](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams-combined-fragment.html#operator-par) Fragment). This can be depicted as follows:

```
@startuml
participant T1
participant T2
participant Main

par
    T1 -> Main ++ #red: start
    Main --> T1 -- #red : done

    else

    T2 -> Main ++ #yellow: start
    Main --> T2 -- #yellow : done
end
@enduml
```

While the `else` keyword is generally used for an **alt/else** fragment, it can also be used in other group types to add a visual separator. The resulting diagram of the above, is shown below.

[image]